# Como crear servicio con notificacion?

Tags: java, android

Hola se puede crear un servicio en segundo plano con una notificacion?
lo que quiero es lanzar una notificacion cuando abro por primera vez la app y el servicio que se inicie cuando se inicia la notificacion y que dure hasta que yo mate la app cuando la ciero del todo,lo que me funciona ahora es la notificacion normal en una clase Servicio pero quiero iniciar el servicio en segundo plano cuando se inicia la notificacion.

por otro lado si pincho la primera vez en la notificacion me abre la app pero si pincho otra vez en la app ya no me lleva en la app.

aqui dejo mi codigo

```
public class Servicio extends Service {
    public Servicio() {
    }

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private final static String CHANNEL_ID = "NOTIFICACION";
    private final static int NOTIFICACION_ID = 0;

    private Resources mResources;

    private String strAppName, srtLiveBroadcast;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();

        mResources = getResources();

        strAppName = mResources.getString(R.string.app_name);
        srtLiveBroadcast = mResources.getString(R.string.live_broadcast1);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mResources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_share );

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Noticacion";
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH );
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID );

        //para abrir MainActivity desde una notificacion
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        builder.setAutoCancel( false );
        builder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher_share );
        builder.setLargeIcon( largeIcon );
        builder.setContentTitle( strAppName );
        builder.setContentText( srtLiveBroadcast );
        builder.setColor( Color.WHITE );
        builder.setSound( null );
        builder.setPriority( NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH );
        builder.setDefaults( Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND );
        builder.setContentIntent( resultPendingIntent );

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from( getApplicationContext() );
        notificationManagerCompat.notify( NOTIFICACION_ID, builder.build() );

    }

    //Metodo para Iniciar el servicio
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio en Ejecucion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    //Metodo para parar el servicio
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

aqui esta mi activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //url a cargar
    String url = "https://google.es";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Servicio.class));

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```